# decimal to binary converter tester class

Tags: java, arrays, binary, decimal, computer-science

I am writing a small program on eclipse for an assignment to convert decimals to binary. These are the instructions for this specific assignment and this is my code so far:

Write a DecToBinConverter class that has a single public static void printInBinary (int n) method that implements the following algorithm:

1. Let S be an empty stack of the type Integer.
2. If n is zero, print 0
3. While n is greater than 0
    a.  rem = n % 2
    b.  push rem into stack S
    c.  n = n / 2
4. While S is not empty
    a.  digit = S.pop()
    b.  print digit

Write a DecToBinConverTester that creates this array:

Integer[] numbers = { new Integer(23),
                      new Integer(47),
                      new Integer(257),
                      new Integer(1023),
                      new Integer(0),
                      new Integer(82),
                      new Integer(512),
                      new Integer(100),
                      new Integer(2049) };
and for each numbers[i] first prints it and then calls the printInBinary method for it.

**My code so far:**

```
package stack;  
public class DecToBinConverter  
{  
    public static void printInBinary (int n)  
    {  
        ArrayStack<Integer> S = new ArrayStack<Integer>(n);    
        if (n == 0)  
        System.out.println ("0");

    while (n > 0)
    {
        int rem = n % 2;
        S.push(rem);
        n = n/2;                    
    }   

    while (n != 0)
    {
        int digit = S.pop();
        System.out.println(digit);          
    }
}
}
```

**and my tester class:**

```
package stack;  
public class DecToBinConverterTester   
{  
    public static void main (String[] args)  
{  
    Integer[] numbers = { new Integer(23),  
                          new Integer(47),  
                          new Integer(257),  
                          new Integer(1023),  
                          new Integer(0),  
                          new Integer(82),  
                          new Integer(512),  
                          new Integer(100),  
                          new Integer(2049) };  

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(numbers.printInBinary(i));
    }
}
```

}

My DecToBinConverter class complies but i am having a little trouble with the tester class. I keep getting an error when trying to invoke the printInBinary method to print. **The exact error says : The method printInBinary() is undefined for the type integer and cannot invoke printInBinary(int) on the array type integer[].** Can someone please explain what that error means or what my code is missing? Thank you :)

Comment: `printInBinary` is a static method. You qualify it with the class name: `DecToBinConverter.printInBinary`, and you send it the *value* to print, not the *index* of the value (in an array the method cannot even access).

Comment: As often seen in questions on this topic, there is no decimal to binary conversion here at all, other than what the *compiler* does when it sees 23,47, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DecToBinConverter.printInBinary(numbers[i]);`

Comment: Why would you need import when they are in the same package?

Comment: @Andreas You are correct. If it is in same package then we need not import. I will edit that out.

Comment: @Tej hi, thank you guys for helping me out. So i did just try that and i was able to compile my tester class but my output looks very incorrect! It just shows up as [Ljava.lang.Integer;@15db9742

Comment: @TWangmo That is not possible with the code recommended. Clearly you did `System.out.println(numbers)`, instead of what was given here.